# HLSL Reflection - how to get the members of a tbuffer?

Tags: reflection, direct3d, hlsl

I can use **GetConstantBufferByIndex** to get a pointer to an **ID3D11ShaderReflectionConstantBuffer** which will allow me to enumerate the members of a cbuffer, but for a tbuffer, I can't find any corresponding function in the D3D Reflection APIs.

Am I missing something or does the reflection system not have a way to enumerate these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetConstantBufferByIndex returns both cbuffers and tbuffers. In D3D's terminology they are both "constant buffers".